# Basic questions on C++ operators?

Tags: c++, operators

I currently have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a;
cout << "Enter a number for a: "; //Prompts the user for a and b inputs
cin >> a;

int b;
cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
cin >> b;

cout << "A is " << a << "\tB is " << b << end1;
cout <<"Sum of a and b is equal to " << a << "+" << b << "and the result is " << (a + b) << end1;
cout <<"Product of a and b is equal to " << a << "*" << b << "and the result is " << (a * b) << end1;
cout <<"a > b is " << a << ">" << b << "and the result is " << (a > b) << end1;
cout <<"a < b is " << a << ">" << b << "and the result is " << (a < b) << end1;
cout <<"a == b is " << a << "==" << b << "and the result is " << (a == b) << end1;
cout <<"a >= b is " << a << ">=" << b << "and the result is " << (a >= b) << end1;
cout <<"a <= b is " << a << "<=" << b << "and the result is " << (a <= b) << end1;
cout <<"a != b is " << a << "!=" << b << "and the result is " << (a != b) << end1;

return 0;
}
```

and I'm receiving these errors

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:44: error: 'end1' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Expanding on the answers, I find it helps to think of `endl` as standing for `end (of) l(ine)`.

Comment: This issues about your professors' level of English is something that you should talk to your university about, and is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Specifically, you should talk either to the head of your academic department, or to the *dean of students*. That's part of their job, and thus part of what your tuition has already paid for, so take advantage of what they have to offer. Bring some of your classmates with you to show it's not just a problem with *you*. Make an appointment in advance to show you've given your complaint some thought.

Comment: You may want to consider bringing it up to your professor before going to the dep. head or dean of students...

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, the edits

- `end1` -> `endl` (*mnemonic: end-of-line*)
- remove semicolons (semicolons *end* the statement, and the next statement would *start* with `<<`?)
- **and** parenthesize sub expressions (in order to get the precedence right)

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/296f05a7c3c599a9)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number for a: "; //Prompts the user for a and b inputs
    cin >> a;
    int b;
    cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "A is "                           << a << "\tB is " << b << endl
         << "Sum of a and b is equal to "     << a << "+"       << b << "and the result is " << (a + b) << endl
         << "Product of a and b is equal to " << a << "*"       << b << "and the result is " << (a * b) << endl
         << "a > b is "                       << a << ">"       << b << "and the result is " << (a > b) << endl
         << "a < b is "                       << a << ">"       << b << "and the result is " << (a < b) << endl
         << "a == b is "                      << a << "=="      << b << "and the result is " << (a == b) << endl
         << "a >= b is "                      << a << ">="      << b << "and the result is " << (a >= b) << endl
         << "a <= b is "                      << a << "<="      << b << "and the result is " << (a <= b) << endl
         << "a != b is "                      << a << "!="      << b << "and the result is " << (a != b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number for a: 3
Enter a number for b: 4
A is 3  B is 4
Sum of a and b is equal to 3+4and the result is 7
Product of a and b is equal to 3*4and the result is 12
a > b is 3>4and the result is 0
a < b is 3>4and the result is 1
a == b is 3==4and the result is 0
a >= b is 3>=4and the result is 0
a <= b is 3<=4and the result is 1
a != b is 3!=4and the result is 1
```

Answer (score 5):

`end1` should be `endl` otherwise this error occurs.

The error is explainnig how the compiler does not know what `end1` is, e.g. not found in the scope. It is simply a misspelling of `endl`, which actually does exist in the scope.

Additionally, you need `cout` in front of each line or not have semicolons until the final output.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is because you used end1<---number 1 instead of endl<---lowercase L

The remaining errors are because you terminated that line with a semicolon. If you want to continue the output as one long expression don'e use semicolons at the ends. Probably more readable would be to use cout at the beginning on each of those lines instead. Like this:

cout << "A is " << a << "\tB is " << b << endl;
cout <<"Sum of a and b is equal to " << a << "+" << b << "and the result is " << a + b << endl;
cout <<"Product of a and b is equal to " << a << "*" << b << "and the result is " << a * b << endl;

Comment: The markdown was mightily upset. Five minutes later and it wouldn't have mattered so much. Shocking cock up. The mice were furious :/

Answer (score 1):

You have `;` at the end of the lines, but no `cout` at the beginning. Once you get to the `;` at the end of the line, it's a new statement, and the compiler doesn't know how to deal with something like `<<"a > b is " << a << ">"`, because at the very least there should be something to the left of `<<` - and whatever is on the left and right of `<<` should also be acceptable to the operator `<<`.

Fix it by adding `cout` in front of the `<<` in relevant places - or make it a really long line by removing the `;` - but if you have an `endl`, then you may just as well start a new `cout` line.

[And as others have pointed out, `endl` is not the same as `end1`]

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;
   cout << "Enter a number for a: "; //Prompts the user for a and b   inputs
   cin >> a;

   int b;
   cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
   cin >> b;

   cout << "A is " << a << "\tB is " << b << endl;
   cout <<"Sum of a and b is equal to " << a << "+" << b << "and the   result is " << (a + b) << endl;
   cout <<"Product of a and b is equal to " << a << "*" << b << "and  the result is " << (a * b) << endl;
   cout <<"a > b is " << a << ">" << b << "and the result is " << (a > b) <<  endl;
   cout <<"a < b is " << a << ">" << b << "and the result is " << (a < b) << endl;
   cout <<"a == b is " << a << "==" << b << "and the result is " << (a == b) << endl;
   cout <<"a >= b is " << a << ">=" << b << "and the result is " << (a >= b) << endl;
   cout <<"a <= b is " << a << "<=" << b << "and the result is " << (a <= b) << endl;
   cout <<"a != b is " << a << "!=" << b << "and the result is " << (a != b) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

u have written 'end1' to represent new line .bt the correct keyword is 'endl'(End of line).the solution is above...

Answer (score 1):

it  is the solution ....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;
   cout << "Enter a number for a: "; //Prompts the user for a and b   inputs
   cin >> a;

   int b;
   cout << "Enter a number for b: ";
   cin >> b;

   cout << "A is " << a << "\tB is " << b << endl;
   cout <<"Sum of a and b is equal to " << a << "+" << b << "and the   result is " << (a + b) << endl;
   cout <<"Product of a and b is equal to " << a << "*" << b << "and  the result is " << (a * b) << endl;
   cout <<"a > b is " << a << ">" << b << "and the result is " << (a > b) <<  endl;
   cout <<"a < b is " << a << ">" << b << "and the result is " << (a < b) << endl;
   cout <<"a == b is " << a << "==" << b << "and the result is " << (a == b) << endl;
   cout <<"a >= b is " << a << ">=" << b << "and the result is " << (a >= b) << endl;
   cout <<"a <= b is " << a << "<=" << b << "and the result is " << (a <= b) << endl;
   cout <<"a != b is " << a << "!=" << b << "and the result is " << (a != b) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please would you summarise the changes you made to the code in the question, for the benefit of the poster.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, it is `endl` and not `end1` (the last char is a L not a 1)

secondly, you will have to put `cout` in front of every line, which begin with the `<<` operator. Then it will work.